# Activation of GPS when the app is already running

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, listener

I'm trying to use the GPS for my android application. In particular I use the coordinates received from the GPS (or alternatively from the 3g connection) to display the user's location on a map. But the user can use the app even when the GPS is off.

My question is: how do I automatically display the user's location after the activation of GPS (or 3g connection) when the application is already running?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you did not already call `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()`, you can listen for the [PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION Broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION) and start requesting location updates/displaying the user location accordingly.

If you already are requesting location updates, you can override your LocationListener's `onProviderDisabled()`/`onProviderEnabled()` methods to be notified when the availability of the provider changes.

Comment: Thanks. I tested the second solution and i added "bestProvider()" to set the right provider in "onProviderDisabled()/onProviderEnabled()" but doesn't work. In detail, it does not work when 3g and gps are disabled and the user activates them when the app is running. Also, when 3g and GPS are off, bestProvider() always returns "network". So I thought to override onStatusChanged() to verify the provider's status for setting automatically the best Provider

Comment: Can you paste your code? What exactly does (not) work, e.g., is your onProviderEnabled() method called?

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. In particular, when the application is running but WiFi or GPS are disabled, bestProvider() return however "network". And in this case, when i activate gps or wifi, the app doesn't recognize them. Also when the application is running and WiFi is on, when i activate GPS, the app doesn't identify it.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapClickListener {

final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
private GoogleMap map;

private TextView tvLocInfo;

private FollowMeLocationSource followMeLocationSource;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
    tvLocInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locinfo);

    followMeLocationSource = new FollowMeLocationSource();

    /* We query for the best Location Provider everytime this fragment is displayed
     * just in case a better provider might have become available since we last displayed it */
    followMeLocationSource.getBestAvailableProvider();

    // Get a reference to the map/GoogleMap object
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    map.setOnMapClickListener(this);

    // TESTMARKER map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    // TESTMARKER map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(41.934977, 12.488708))
    // TESTMARKER .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
       "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
     GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
    }

    /* We query for the best Location Provider everytime this fragment is displayed
     * just in case a better provider might have become available since we last displayed it */
    followMeLocationSource.getBestAvailableProvider();

    // Get a reference to the map/GoogleMap object
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    //Enable the my-location layer (this causes our LocationSource to be automatically activated.)
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    /* Disable the my-location layer (this causes our LocationSource to be automatically deactivated.) */
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.        
    if (map == null) {
        FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment 
         = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();

        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (map != null) {
            Location location = followMeLocationSource.getLastKnownLocation();
            LatLng latlng= new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));

            // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.
            // Replace the (default) location source of the my-location layer with our custom LocationSource
            map.setLocationSource(followMeLocationSource);
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15f));

        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
 tvLocInfo.setText(point.toString());
 map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
}

/* Our custom LocationSource. 
 * We register this class to receive location updates from the Location Manager
 * and for that reason we need to also implement the LocationListener interface. */
private class FollowMeLocationSource implements LocationSource, LocationListener {

    private final Criteria myCriteria = new Criteria();
    private String bestAvailableProvider;
    LocationManager myLocationManager = null;
    OnLocationChangedListener myLocationListener = null;

    /* Updates are restricted to one every 10 seconds, and only when
     * movement of more than 10 meters has been detected.*/
    private final int minTime = 10000;     // minimum time interval between location updates, in milliseconds
    private final int minDistance = 10;    // minimum distance between location updates, in meters

    private FollowMeLocationSource() {
        // Get reference to Location Manager
        myLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Specify Location Provider criteria
        myCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        myCriteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        myCriteria.setBearingRequired(true);

    }

    private void getBestAvailableProvider() {
        /* The prefered way of specifying the location provider (e.g. GPS, NETWORK) to use 
         * is to ask the Location Manager for the one that best satisfies our criteria.
         * By passing the 'true' boolean we ask for the best available (enabled) provider. */
        bestAvailableProvider = myLocationManager.getBestProvider(myCriteria, true);
        Log.i("Best Provider:", bestAvailableProvider);
    }

    private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
        Location lastKnownLocation = myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestAvailableProvider);
        Double lat = lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
        return lastKnownLocation;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        /* Push location updates to the registered listener..
         * (this ensures that my-location layer will set the blue dot at the new/received location) */
        Log.i("EntradentroOnLocationChanged", "Entrato");
        if (myLocationListener != null) {
               myLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location);

               double lat = location.getLatitude();
               double lon = location.getLongitude();

               tvLocInfo.setText(
                 "lat: " + lat + "\n" +
                 "lon: " + lon);
              }
        // ..and Animate camera to center on that location
        //LatLng latlng= new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        //map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));         
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        getBestAvailableProvider();

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        getBestAvailableProvider();

    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    /* Activates this provider. This provider will notify the supplied listener
     * periodically, until you call deactivate(). */
    @Override
    public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener) {
        // We need to keep a reference to my-location layer's listener so we can push forward
        // location updates to it when we receive them from Location Manager.
        myLocationListener = listener;
        // Request location updates from Location Manager
        if (bestAvailableProvider != null) {
            myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestAvailableProvider, minTime, minDistance, this);
        } else {
            // TODO (Display a message/dialog) No Location Providers currently available.
        }

    }

    /* Deactivates this provider.
     * This method is automatically invoked by disabling my-location layer. */
    @Override
    public void deactivate() {
        // Remove location updates from Location Manager
        myLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        myLocationListener = null;
    }

}
```

}